# Docker build crashes whole machine when transferring build context

Tags: laravel, docker, ubuntu

My machine crashes when I try to build an docker image. I can only build once and then the machine crashes when I try to start a second build.

It always starts and then starts to transfer to the build context, and around the 150-170mb mark it locks up the machine needing a restart to get it back.

I have not been able to find any logs regarding to any errors so I am completely in the dark.

I am running Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
In the codeblock below you can find the system specifications

`docker info` output:

```
Client:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  app: Docker App (Docker Inc., v0.9.1-beta3)
  buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc., v0.9.1-docker)
  compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc., v2.10.2)
  scan: Docker Scan (Docker Inc., v0.17.0)

Server:
 Containers: 13
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 13
 Images: 189
 Server Version: 20.10.18
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
  userxattr: false
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: systemd
 Cgroup Version: 2
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux runc io.containerd.runc.v2
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 9cd3357b7fd7218e4aec3eae239db1f68a5a6ec6
 runc version: v1.1.4-0-g5fd4c4d
 init version: de40ad0
 Security Options:
  apparmor
  seccomp
   Profile: default
  cgroupns
 Kernel Version: 5.15.0-47-generic
 Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 12 (Added by Author: Model Intel Core i5-11400H)
 Total Memory: 15.36GiB 
 Name: SHENZHOU
 ID: RA4Z:367M:Z7EV:ODMX:IT5C:ZARV:NAAO:KZHX:D3VN:544G:UWA7:U27Q
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Comment: Why do you need such large files for your build context? Have you tried adding a dockerignore file to the project?

Comment: @OneCricketeer, i have added files to the dockerignore, but the vendor and the node_modules dependencies are big for this project.

Comment: You should exclude node_modules folder rather than copy it into the container